# Python: Using a For Loop and random function in statistical probabiltiy model

Tags: python-3.x

I have been set a task, to using an original Dataset of 25 A's and C's (50 data points in total), to randomly select 1 of the 50 data points then add this to a new nested list and to repeat this 50 times (length of dataset). This random selection then needs to be done again with the new dataset, for 25 times.

```
import random
SetSize = 50
StatData = [[] for b in range(1,50)]
    for i in range(0, int(SetSize/2)):           
StatData[0].append('A') 
    for i in range(int(SetSize/2)):           
StatData[0].append('C')

for a in range(1,25):
    for b in range(0, int(SetSize)):
        StatData(a+1).append(random.choice(StatData[a]))
```

This is my current piece of code, so i have created the empty nested list, created the initial dataset (StatData0) however the next section is not working it is returning
    "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all. You cannot call a list.

### Typo

On the last line of the code you provided, change

```
StatData(a+1).appen...
```

to

```
StatData[a+1].appen...
```

and I guess it should fix the error.

### Index problem (edit)

You are populating the list of index 0 with As and Bs (StatData[0]) but in your last loop `a` goes from 1 to 50. So your first iteration will choose a random character in StatData[1] (which is empty) thus throwing another error.

Starting your loop from the index 0 should make this go away !

Comment: it is now returning two more errors                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Statistics.py", line 12, in <module>
    StatData[a+1].append(random.choice(StatData[a]))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Comment: @DB7 yes, you are adding your first As and Cs to the list of index 0 (StatData[0]). But you last loop starts from index 1. And StatData[1] is empty so it cannot choose values from that list. **updated my answer**